# How do I store a string with a `"` in it?

Tags: python, json

I want to have a JSON object with the value of an attribute as a string with the character `"`. 
For example:

```
{
"Dimensions" : " 12.0" x 9.6" "
}
```

Obviously this is not possible. How do I do this?
With Python.

Comment: As an alternative, use unicode and the DOUBLE PRIME character for inches :) { "Dimensions" : u" 12.0″ x 9.6″ " } . Half-jokingly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Isaac is correct.

As for how to do it in python, you need to provide a more detailed explanation of how you are building your `JSON` object.  For example, let's say you're using no external libraries and are doing it manually (ridiculous, I know), you would do this:

```
>>> string = "{ \"Dimensions\" : \" 12.0\\\" x 9.6\\\" \" }"
>>> print string
{ "Dimensions" : " 12.0\" x 9.6\" " }
```

Obviously this is kind of silly.  If you are using the standard python json module, try this:

```
from json import JSONEncoder
encoder = JSONEncoder()
string = encoder.encode({ "Dimensions":" 12.0\" x 9.6\" " })

>>> print string
{"Dimensions": " 12.0\" x 9.6\" "}
```

which is the desired result.

Answer (score 3):

Python has two symbols you can use to specify string literals, the single quote and the double quote.

For example:
    my_string = "I'm home!"

Or, more relevant to you,

```
>>> string = '{ "Dimensions" : " 12.0\\\" x 9.6\\\" " }'
>>> print string
{ "Dimensions" : " 12.0\" x 9.6\" " }
```

You can also prefix the string with 'r' to specify it is a raw string, so backslash escaped sequences are not processed, making it cleaner.

```
>>> string = r'{ "Dimensions" : " 12.0\" x 9.6\" " }'
>>> print string
{ "Dimensions" : " 12.0\" x 9.6\" " }
```

Answer (score 1):

JSON.stringify, if using Javascript, will escape it for you.
If not, you can escape them like \" (put a \ in front)
Edit: in Python, try [re.escape()](http://ayaz.wordpress.com/2007/04/22/reescape-pythons-equivalent-of-phps-addslashes/) or just replace all " with \":

```
"json string".replace("\"","\\\"");
```

Comment: Oh ok. Is there a way to do the escaping in python?